# Would it be conceivable to create a lightsaber shield from a plethora of lightsabers arranged in an umbrella-like pattern?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

Using an umbrella-based design pattern could then allow it to be  folded away for ease-of-carry...?

Comment: You can place lightsabers in any arrangement you want, of course this design would be useless as the middle would be vulnerable. A lightsaber is intended to be used as a saber.

Comment: Yes. Of course.

Comment: Conceivable as in can we Conceive of it, or was it don in-universe?

Comment: There are deflector shields that do this already.  Look at the battle droids.  With out the limitation of being hand held or the risk of accidentally having yourself cored by a strong hit.

Comment: It looks to me that a lightsaber was just a bunch of plasma contained in a force shield and that when lightsabers parry each other it is the force shields that is making the contact. If you want a shield, then just use a shield, as seen several times in the movies.

Comment: I'd think a shield made of lightsaber resistant metal would be more effective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a proper lightsaber probably not, given the design weaknesses already pointed out here. However, given that there are numerous variations on the design of light-weapons, most notably the [lightwhip](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightwhip), it seems that it is possible to drastically change the shape of the actual blade.

It is therefore not a stretch to assume it is possible to shape the blade into a rigid, bent form. If you can do this, **you can have your umbrella design, but have the blade bend back at the outer point, returning to the middle, to protect the hilt section.**

It's a crude design, but it should work, and although it looks clunky if you picture it in your head; since the lightsaber blade doesn't weigh anything, it should remain quite wieldy.

You could even (as a second design idea), have the blade bend out, much like a hook. Roughly like this:

[image: hook]

If you image the bottom part ending in the hilt, you could then bundle them all together and get a proper umbrella. You could also flatten the blade on the outer region to reduce the number of required weapons.

Comment: Once they let the lightwhip into canon there really are few structures which don't seem plausble.

Answer (score 3):

If you are thinking of a circular shield, where you have either one bladed or two bladed lightsabers, with all the handles converging in the center, then that structure would be vulnerable at the center region.

A lightsaber wielder would just slice the center of your shield and some or all of your lightsabers would "go offline".

However, you could enhance this design by making it a semisphere of lightsabers - from the same center, have lightsabers pointing at different angles outward. This should defend you from all frontal attacks. (the key here: the more lightsabers, the better)

Of course, you also need a way of keeping the center (all the handles) together, and you need to be able to actually hold the shield as well. A magnet with a handle might come in handy.

Coming to think of it this might actually be more of a weapon than a shield though...

Comment: For added hilarity, blaster bolts which hit the shield would bounce randomly!

Comment: @Jeff Also you could theoretically cook your dinner while defending from it.